# Rebol Plugin install procedure on IE and when will it be available for Firefox?

Tags: rebol

I just installed Rebol Plugin on IE. What happens when a user connect to a rebol script demo without this plugin. Will he be asked to install it automatically ?

When will Rebol Plugin available for Firefox ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and has been for sometime.

It may even still work!

See http://www.rebol.org/ml-display-message.r?m=rmlNRHC

Comment: Unfortunately it's for old firefox. I found another one more recent but still too old https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/1879/